# How to check whether system has x86 or x64 MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to check that which type of MySQL my system has (as in x86 or x64 [32 or 64 bit]).

Any way to check that this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to find is using mysql to find it

MYSQL on 32 Bit System

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_machine';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| version_compile_machine | i686 |
+-------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

MYSQL on 64 Bit System

```
mysql> show variables like 'version_compile_machine';
+-------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+-------------------------+--------+
| version_compile_machine | x86_64 |
+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: both give me X86. are their any way to upgrade to x64